# Converting c++ tm struct and mktime to C#

Tags: c#, c++, datetime, date-conversion, mktime

I'm converting some c++ to c# code. I cannot reproduce equivalent values when converting from the `tm` struct and `mktime()` to c#.

Example:
Both versions use the same values:

```
int year = 2022;
int month = 9;
int day = 5;
int hour = 0;
int minute = 27;
int second = 20;
```

In C++:

```
struct tm sampleTime;
unsigned long longTime;
sampleTime.tm_year = year;
sampleTime.tm_mon  = month - 1;
sampleTime.tm_mday = day;
sampleTime.tm_hour = hour;
sampleTime.tm_min  = minute;
sampleTime.tm_sec  = second;
sampleTime.tm_wday = 0;
sampleTime.tm_yday = 0;
sampleTime.tm_isdst= 0;

longTime = mktime(&thistime);
```

The value of `longTime` is `1662366439`.

In C#:

```
DateTime sampleTime = new DateTime(year, month, day, hour, minute, second);
DateTime unixEpoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
ulong longTime = (ulong)(sampleTime - unixEpoch).TotalSeconds;
```

The value of `longTime` is `1662337639`.

So they are very close but off, and I need them to be equivalent. What am I missing here?

Comment: Forget C++ exists, and implement date and time according to the best practices of C#.  Do not attempt to "translate" what C++ does to C# by doing line-by-line translations.  I am sure C# has a way to do this, irrespective of how C++ does this.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I hear ya but the values need to match because they are used in calculations and stored values from a long time ago (until they can be updated).

Comment: C# uses .NET for what it attempts to accomplish, while C++ does not.  You are trying to make two totally different things have exactly the same value, and neither of them are under your control.  Also, let's say you get some values to match -- what will you do when you get that bug report that some odd value out of thousands doesn't match?  It may be a losing game trying to fix that "bug", only to introduce a bug somewhere else.

Comment: The difference is 8 hours. That suggests to me that the cause is in accounting for timezones or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mktime()` takes in a `tm` expressed in *local time*, whereas the Unix epoch is expressed in *UTC time* instead.

The C# `DateTime()` constructors you are calling don't know whether the specified date/time values are in *local time* or *UTC time*, so the `Kind` property of the resulting `DateTime`s is `Unspecified`, which can cause calculation errors.  So, you need to use other `DateTime` constructors that make each `Kind` explicit so adjustments can be made as needed during calculations, eg:

```cs
DateTime sampleTime = new DateTime(year, month, day, hour, minute, second, DateTimeKind.Local);
DateTime unixEpoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
```

---

That being said, note that the C++ code is setting `sampleTime.tm_isdst = 0` to indicate that the specified date/time *IS NOT* in DST time, even if the real date/time actually *IS* in DST time.

I'm not sure how to handle that on the C# side. You will *probably* have to lookup whether the specified `sampleTime` is actually in DST (ie, via [`TimeZoneInfo.Local.IsDaylightSavingTime()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.isdaylightsavingtime?view=net-8.0)) and if so then adjust it accordingly to move it out of DST before then performing further calculations on it, eg:

```
DateTime sampleTime = new DateTime(year, month, day, hour, minute, second, DateTimeKind.Local);
DateTime unixEpoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);

TimeZoneInfo tz = TimeZoneInfo.Local;
if (tz.SupportsDaylightSavingTime && if tz.IsDaylightSavingTime(sampleTime))
{
    // figure out the difference between Standard/Daylight times
    // for this timezone at the specified date/time and adjust 
    // sampleTime accordingly ...
}
```

Comment: I think you're right about the DST, didn't catch that. Not sure how would I adjust it but I'll mess around with it. Thanks!